# finding indices of multiple corresponding rows of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices and I want to find the indices of rows in Matrix `B` which have the same row values in Matrix `A`. Let me give a simple example:

```
A=[1,2,3; 2,3,4; 3,5,7; 1,2,3; 1,2,3; 5,8,6];
B=[1,2,3; 29,3,4; 3,59,7; 1,29,3; 1,2,3; 5,8,6;1,2,3];
```

For example, for first row in matrix `A`, The row1, row5, and row7 in Matrix `B` are correspondences. 
I have written below code but it doesn't return back all indices which have the same row value in matrix `A` and only one of them (row7) is backed !!

```
A_sorted = sort(A,2,'descend'); % sorting angles
B_sorted = sort(B,2,'descend');   % sorting angles
[~,indx]=ismember(A_sorted,B_sorted,'rows')
```

the result is

```
indx_2 =

 7
 0
 0
 7
 7
 6
```

It means for the first row in matrix `A` , only one row ( row 7) in Matrix `B` is available !! But as you can see for first row in matrix `A` there is three correspondent rows in matrix `B` (Row 1, row 5 and row 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best strategy is to apply `ismember` to unique rows

```
%make matrix unique
[B_unique,B2,B3]=unique(B_sorted,'rows')
[~,indx]=ismember(A_sorted,B_unique,'rows')
%For each row in B_unique, get the corresponding indices in B_sorted
indx2=arrayfun(@(x)find(B3==x),indx,'uni',0)
```

Comment: THX, That's a wise solution . it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare all pairs of rows between `A` and `B`, use

```
E = squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(B, [3 2 1])), 2));
```

or equivalently

```
E = pdist2(A,B)==0;
```

In your example, this gives

```
E =
     1     0     0     0     1     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     1     0     1
     1     0     0     0     1     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

The value `E(ia,ib)` tells you if the `ia`-th row of `A` equals the `ib`-th row of `B`.